# terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::system_error: mutex lock failed: Invalid argument

Tags: ios, objective-c

If my app in on foreground, then I open app switcher then for quit my app, it'll crash. In the console there are:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::system_error: mutex lock failed: Invalid argument
```

But if I bring it to background, then I open app switcher then for quit my app, it won't crash.

Comment: any results on this? I have today similar situation

Comment: @PawełMadej have you found any solution?

Comment: @ZiyaddinSadigov not yet unfortunately

Comment: Hi guys, I got this error and could not find the reason for it. Did anyone of you guys got its solution?